# How to clean up promise data in react hook?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

```
// Home.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Todo from "../components/Todo";
import { firestore } from "../database/firebase";

export default function Home() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    firestore
      .collection("todos")
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        setTodos(
          snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
            return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() };
          })
        );
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {todos.map(todo => (
        <Todo
          key={todo.id}
          id={todo.id}
          title={todo.title}
        ></Todo>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

I had this simple todo app, where I update todos state when I get data back from firestore.

Above useEffect set my todos as [{id:"123", title : "work"}, ...].

But, I want to put all firestore getter in one file and simple call

```
useEffect(() => {
  getTodos().then(data=>setTodos(data))
})
```

Then how should I define getTodos function? I tried below code and with many variations, like adding async and await, but none of them worked.

```
// firestore.js
export const getTodos = () => {
  return firestore
    .collection("todos")
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() };
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: you are not returning the `snapshot.docs.map` result

Comment: Could you be more specific on that?

Comment: in the lambda `snapshot => { snapshot.docs.map(...)}` you forgot the return statement. try `snapshot => { return snapshot.docs.map(...)}` or simply remove curly braces

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel that won't work because the scope of the return statement is not correct. You'd be returning the callback function rather than the getTodos function.

Comment: @silencedogood the scope is in the `then` - I don't understand why it dooesn't work

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel consider the scope. When you call `.then()`, you are inserting a callback function within the `.then` declaration. This creates its own function scope, so when you call `return`, it's returning the callback function, not the `getTodos` function.

Comment: @silencedogood the `return` inside the `then` is returning the result of the `map`. If you don't then there is nothing in the promise returned by `getTodos`, that's why the OP can't set the data.

Comment: @silencedogood I link you a snippet with a similar code https://repl.it/repls/FinancialTestyBoard

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel I understand our misunderstanding now (how's that for funny wording). We are both correct, just talking about different things. Nonetheless I don't want to clog up the comments anymore. Good day my friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizing async/await syntax will allow you to clean things up and give you the desired result. You'll need to change things up a bit. Try something like this:

```
export const getTodos = async function() {

   const data = await firestore.collection("todos").get();
   const dataArr = data.docs.map(doc => {
    return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() };
  });

  return dataArr;
};
```

Comment: Calling getTodos().then(data=>console.log(data)) prints null for some reason

Comment: @Sean I modified the answer. Let me know if this is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution without async/await.

```js
// firestore.js
export const getTodos = () => (
  firestore
    .collection("todos")
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => (
      snapshot.docs.map((({ id, data }) => (
        { id, ...data() }
      ))
    ))
);
```